# Set Search Parameter for Google Drive Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm having an issue setting the search parameter `q` for the Google drive Javascript SDK. I've found an answer on Stackoverflow. However, that didn't work for me. Here's my `GET` request URI that I'm using from the Postman and Postman returns the data fine.

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='0B_J9f9IAYIKQdllaQXJQXzMyZm8'+in+parents&orderBy=name`

I'm using the following Javascript code to pass the search query `q` data like the above URL parameters.

```
    function retrieveAllFilesInFolder(folderId, callback) {
        var retrievePageOfChildren = function(request, result) {
            request.execute(function(resp) {
                result = result.concat(resp.items);
                var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
                if (nextPageToken) {
                    request = gapi.client.drive.children.list({
                        'folderId' : folderId,
                        'pageToken': nextPageToken
                    });
                    retrievePageOfChildren(request, result);
                } else {
                    callback(result);
                }
            });
        };

        var initialRequest = gapi.client.drive.children.list({
            'folderId' : folderId,
            'q' : "'" + folderId + "'" + '+in+parents'
        });
        retrievePageOfChildren(initialRequest, []);
    }

retrieveAllFilesInFolder(file.id, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

The above code returns `Array [ undefined ]`. Please, can anyone let me know how do I pass the `q` search parameters correctly that would be exactly similar to the above API URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208824/setting-search-parameters-for-javascript-google-drive-api

Comment: you're using a q which is part of files.list, not children.list. I suggest stick to files.list and test using the Try Now feature of the docs. Once you have it working there, it's easy to compare the working http from the dev console with your app.