# Adding string values to Google Drive SDK search in for loop

Tags: javascript, string, google-drive-api

I am trying to iterate through an array of file types (really just partial file names) and am having a hard time inserting each search item into the code.

just one file type works as `DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains '.wav'');` but I'm going to need more than one file type/partial name in the future.

I'm not good at working with strings in code, especially understanding ' ' and " ". if anyone has any resources or knows how to make this code work I would appreciate it!

Thanks!

```
 var fileType = ['.wav','CSV'];

for(i=0;i<fileType.length; i++){ 

var title = '"' + 'title contains' + fileType[i] + '"'

var wavFiles = DriveApp.searchFiles(title);

var files = wavFiles;

 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();

       file.setTrashed(true);


   };
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but heads up that https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files has a fullFileExtension property which migth be useful.

Comment: Check the [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters#examples) for the correct way of writing queries. There's also a snippet for NodeJS for you since you're using Javascript. You can also check this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208824/setting-search-parameters-for-javascript-google-drive-api) for additional code snippets.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't believe the solution to my problem is in using other search functions. I believe my problem is inserting an item from the array into the phrase "title contains"  and then inserting that into ".searchFiles(insert complete search string here)". I have an identical code that takes the entire file name from the array and it works. But this code needs to accept only partial titles. Does that make sense?